# Is it possible to run Android on iOS?

Tags: ios, startup, android

Ok so I was thinking, Can you run Android on a iOS device? I did some research and Android could run on ARM (Most apps would not work) but how come no one has tried to run it. Whats holding them back?

Answer (score 4):

Many reasons

1. You cannot create another file system
2. No firmware exists for this
3. It would void your warranty
4. Android device developers spend a lot of time developing their hardware and software to work together, just like iOS.
5. The amount of effort required (boot ROM firmware  modifications, bricked devices, etc) makes it much easier just to buy an Android if you *really* want one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool or way to do this by yourself. Theoretically, you could run Android on iOS but it would be near impossible. To do this, someone would have to reverse engineer Android and figure out how to dual boot an iOS device. It has been done in the past with the iPhone 2g and the iDroid project so it is possible but it has not been continued. If you have a computer, you can run Android on your computer using [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/). However, at the moment, there is no way to run Android on your iOS devices.